# Why doesn't Visual Studio allow committing to Git while compiling/building?

Tags: git, visual-studio

Why does the Visual Studio IDE disable committing to Git while building/compiling the code, when you can e.g. do so just fine using the command line or even any IDE made by JetBrains?

Generally, compiled code isn't even tracked in Git, so what's the deal with that restriction?

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's to keep things simple. Commit is one of the few git operations that does not change the source. Most other operations would cause undefined behavior while building.